# Select field where a column has more than n elements SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, having-clause

look this:

Given the table "Customer" that has the following columns:

```
• Name1  First name of the customer.
• Name2  Second Name of the customer.
• Surname1  Customer's First Surname.
• Surname2  Second Surname of the client.
• T_Documento  Type of customer document
• N_Document  Customer document number
• Country_Residence  Country where the Client Resides
```

**PROBLEN TO SOLVE: Write a check that lists the Countries of Residence with less than 10 clients.**

I have been looking for the right code but I still with out find any solution

```
SELECT * (
SELECT pais_residencia, COUNT(*) AS ClientesTotales
FROM Clientes
GROUP BY pais_residencia
) FROM Clientes
WHERE ClientesTotales > 10
```

this is wrong btw...

any idea

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, provided that you change `>` to `<` in the outer query (and add `FROM` in the outer query to introduce the subquery).

But it can be simplified. You don't need a subquery to filter on the count, you can use a  `having` clause instead:

```
SELECT pais_residencia, COUNT(*) AS ClientesTotales
FROM Clientes
GROUP BY pais_residencia 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 10
```

MySQL even supports reusing alias in the `HAVING` clause, which can be phrased:

```
HAVING ClientesTotales < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want *less than 10 clientes* then you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT pais_residencia, COUNT(*) AS ClientesTotales
      FROM Clientes
      GROUP BY pais_residencia
     ) r
WHERE ClientesTotales < 10;
```

The direction of your comparison is wrong, based on the question.

In addition, there are some other syntactic problems with your query -- the subquery should be part of the `FROM` clause, for instance.

You don't need a subquery for this.  You can just use `HAVING`:

If you want less than 10 clientes then you want:

```
SELECT pais_residencia, COUNT(*) AS ClientesTotales
FROM Clientes
GROUP BY pais_residencia
HAVING ClientesTotales < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display all data from a table,
you can use this code

```
select
     name1,
     name2,
     surname1,
     surname2,
     t_documento,
     N_Document,
     country_residence
 FROM
     (
         SELECT
             name1,
             name2,
             surname1,
             surname2,
             t_documento,
             n_document,
             country_residence,
             COUNT(country_residence) OVER(
                 PARTITION BY country_residence
             ) clientestotales
         FROM
             clientes
     )
 WHERE
     clientestotales < 10;
```